# PCI to PCIe 1x bridge compatible with AlmaLinux 8.6

Tags: pcie

I have a mother board with only PCIe slots. I need to plug in a PCI board I have in stock. I know that the PCIe version of this board is 1X.

There exist some PCI to PCIe bridges like [this one](https://www.startech.com/fr-fr/cartes-additionelles-et-peripheriques/pex1pci1). But it is not compatible with the bracket of my board. The problem is that it makes it higher.

I am alright to use a flat wire but I have them to find a solution to fix the board in the PC.

Most of all, the bridge needs to be Linux compatible. Precisely, I use AlmaLinux 8.6.

Does someone can recommend me an appropriate bridge?

Answer (score 0):

You can just plug that right into the PCIe slot without any worries. You don't need anything special, and molex connectors are the last thing I would use for power.

It might look a little goofy but it should work just fine without anything extra, I could be misunderstanding what you're asking but as long as I've tinkered with PCs it should plug into the slot regardless if its x1